# NG2 pdf-viewer src incomplete

Tags: pdf-viewer

In the `ts` file the `pdfSrc` like `blob:http://localhost:4200/5dbf7415-f051-429a-8fd7-10e8a56455f3`

```
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(
    atob(base64)
        .split("")
        .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0))
);
const file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: "application/pdf" });
this.pdfSrc = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

When I check elements the `pdfSrc` is incomplete like `blob:http://localhost:4200/5db`

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfsrc" (error)="onError($event)" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

How to get complete `pdfSrc`?